# how to retrieve bulk data from sql without slowing down the server/program

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

i have a program wherein it will retrieve data from sql based on a specific date range.. the problem is when the date range is set to a year or greater than that then the loading of data is so slow that sometimes the program will be not responding. Is there a way avoid this?

Comment: How much data is in a year? Do you have indexes on your table? What does your query look like?

Comment: More information would be needed: Is it synchronous? How much data is coming back? Is the SQL query quick, or is it hanging in the DB? Is it even possible to batch this data? Is it acceptable to bring back only the first 100 records, and then retrieve the others on demand?

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data in a background thread using the BackgroundWorker component.

It will still take time, but the program won't be frozen.

Alternatively, you can modify your program to load less data.
For example, you can move the logic that uses the data to a sproc on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to prevent the user selecting a date range that is so large.

This may appear restrictive but usually when the user is presented with 10,000 separate records, they realise they need to make their query more specific. The time taken to retrieve the large data set is just a waste of server, network and the user's time.